# Emit event from database callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I try to raise events from inside of a database callback.

My first step is to register all event handlers in function *registerEventHandlers*. Afterwards, I select the database (MongoDb - npm *mongodb*) and validate the result.

Within this result validation, I try to raise several events.

I understand, that the variable/constant *articleEvents* is not present in *toArray()*,however I didn't found any other way to populate this variable inside this function

**This is not working**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const articleEvents = new EventEmitter();

// some imports and requirements
function createDocument(document) {

    [...]

    // register event handlers
    registerEventHandlers()

    // validate article -> the events will be raised here
    validateArticle(articleDatabase, document);

    // we need to cleanup a litte bit (to prevent memory leaks)
    articleEvents.removeAllListeners();
}

function validateArticle(database = Object, article = {}) {

    // variable definition
    [...]

    try {

        // check if uploaded article is deprecated
        if (checkIfDeprecated(article.condition)) {

            // raise event - isDeprecated
            articleEvents.emit('isDeprecated', article);  // <- this one is working

        }

        // create query
        

        // select database -> determine, if article is existing
        database.find(query, projection).toArray((error, resultDocument) => {
    
            // validate error
            if (error) {

                // raise event - error
                articleEvents.emit('error', new Error({ error: error }))   // <- this one is not working

            }

            [...]
            // all other events are not working either

        });

    } catch (error) {

        // emit event - error
        articleEvents.emit('error', new Error({ error: "error -> an unexpected error occured", content: error }));

    }
}

function registerEventHandlers() { });

    // my event handlers
    articleEvents.on('isNotExisting', (document) => { });
    articleEvents.on('isDeprecated', (document) => { });
    articleEvents.on('logicalError', (error) => { });
    articleEvents.on('error', (error) => { });
    articleEvents.on('unhandledEvent', (unhandledError) => { });
}

function checkIfDeprecated(conditions = []) {
    [...]
    return isDeprecated;   // bool -> true/false
}
```

If you see any syntax errors inside this code block -> there are no syntax errors in my code. This is just an excerpt

Please let me know if you miss any kind of information.

So - is there a way, to adress *articleEvents* inside of the database callback?

I've searched several days, but found no proper answer.

**This is working**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const articleEvents = new EventEmitter();

// some imports and requirements
function createDocument(document) {

    [...]

    // register event handlers
    registerEventHandlers()

    // validate article -> the events will be raised here
    validateArticle(articleDatabase, document);

    // we need to cleanup a litte bit (to prevent memory leaks)
    articleEvents.removeAllListeners();
}

function validateArticle(database = Object, article = {}) {

    // variable definition
    [...]

    try {

        // check if uploaded article is deprecated
        if (checkIfDeprecated(article.condition)) {

            // raise event - isDeprecated
            articleEvents.emit('isDeprecated', article);  // <- this one is working

        }

        // create query
        

        // select database -> determine, if article is existing
        database.find(query, projection).toArray((error, resultDocument) => {
    
            // regiser event handlers 
            registerEventHandlers();

            // validate error
            if (error) {

                // raise event - error
                articleEvents.emit('error', new Error({ error: error }))   // <- this one is not working

            }

            [...]
            // all other events are not working either

        });

    } catch (error) {

        // emit event - error
        articleEvents.emit('error', new Error({ error: "error -> an unexpected error occured", content: error }));

    }
}

function registerEventHandlers() { });

    // my event handlers
    articleEvents.on('isNotExisting', (document) => { });
    articleEvents.on('isDeprecated', (document) => { });
    articleEvents.on('logicalError', (error) => { });
    articleEvents.on('error', (error) => { });
    articleEvents.on('unhandledEvent', (unhandledError) => { });
}

function checkIfDeprecated(conditions = []) {
    [...]
    return isDeprecated;   // bool -> true/false
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess, it's closure in arrow function. Maybe you can try to declare your arrow function inside toArray as normal function - same level as `function registerEventHandlers()`.

Comment: @ThinhTran Thanks for this hint. This will work now. However its a little confusing, that I need to declare my event handler 2 times.

Comment: Does it work? I don't understand this part `declare my event handler 2 times`. Can you update and share your code again?

Comment: Yes, it works. I need to declare the event handler 2 times. First: in function `createDocument` and second time inside the callback

Comment: seems to be because of `articleEvents.removeAllListeners();`. You still need the handler in callback but they already removed because of that call.

Comment: Ok. Now I see my fault. I've removed my event listeners before I got the results from the database. I've fixed my code. Thanks for the help.

It's working now